# How to bypass express's error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

Express's error handling is very nice on the surface, allowing the dev to route any errors through error handling middleware. However, given the nature of javascript, there are definitely times when a thrown error should crash the process to avoid a more serious situation like undead connections, perpetually locked db rows, etc.

When an error occurs from which my app is unable to recover, how do I cause this kind of crash (or better yet trigger a graceful shutdown)? Re-throwing the error within an error-handling middleware just passes it along to the next one...

I know I can `process.exit(1)` but I feel like express should have a way to deal with this, given that it is catching the errors in the first place.

Comment: Express Error Handling by default exits the application. By implementing yourself the middleware with arity 4 (error middleware) you can manage personally the behavior of your app in case of errors. Note that using Express Error Middleware is not enough: try to "setTimetout(function () {console.log(someUndefinedVariable.someUndefinedProperty);}, 1000)" inside an Express route handler and you'll observe that you don't pass through the Error Middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "domains", check out these:

- http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html
- http://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors

Comment: This is really helpful in pointing me in the right direction. I found an example of this in action at https://github.com/brianc/node-domain-middleware/blob/master/index.js